# how to pass video from android to opencv on pyton?

Tags: python, android, opencv

I have a project on android studio that import video from a gallery, and what I need to do is to integrate the python opencv with the android studio,

my module on opencv analyze the video, and captures the frame if something was detected.
What is the correct way to do this?

In the end I want to take each frame of photo which was detected by opencv, and upload this photo of the frame to mysql table.

Comment: Stream the video over TCP...?

Comment: right now, just import a video from the gallery, and send the video to opencv.